# ¿cual es la solución ? a este problema con cx_freeze y tl.testing.thread en python

Tags: python

Bueno tengo un pequeño problema con mi programa ya que estoy utilizando from tl.testing.thread import ThreadJoiner al momento de ejecutar desde consola el programa corre de maravilla el problema es cuando creo el archivo ejecutable me dice que el modulo tl no se encuentra,mi duda es como se debe importar al setup.py?¿a cual libreria pertenece? ya que tl no la reconoce tl.testing tampoco y para test dicho modulo no lo encuentra.

mi setup.py:

```
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable
import cx_Freeze
import sys
buildOptions = dict(packages =   ["os","math","tkinter","sqlite3","datetime","random","PIL","playsound","threading","test"],
    excludes = ["matplotlib","pandas","lmxl","http","html","pymysql","socket"],
    include_files=['c:/users/the-hacker/appData/local/programs/python/python36-32/DLLs/tcl86t.dll',
     'c:/users/the-hacker/appData/local/programs/python/python36-32/DLLs/tk86t.dll',"bd_rpg"],
)
```

He creado varios ejecutables y me corren normal solo es esa linea en mi archivo principal "from tl.testing.thread import ThreadJoiner" a la que no encuentra como ejecutar.
aqui les dejo la imagen del error y como seve el programa.[image: terminal_vs_exe.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya resolvi el problema de la forma mas sencilla para que se ejecutara mi programa solo copie el paquete "tl" de la carpeta "Lib\site-packages" a la carpeta "Lib" luego de aplicar "python setup.py build" el programa corre como deseaba.
[image: mi_juego.jpg]